# Indian Citizen and living in Uk and doing Free lancing

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, india

I moved to UK in Aug 2014 as my husband's dependent and now got an offer from a freelancing company. They want me to setup an account in UK so that they can do payments in pounds. I am moving back in India this month so i need to know can i accept payments in my Uk account being in India. Is it legal to run an account in UK when you are based in india and how would take care of my taxes.